# SD card insert/remove behaviors not detected until running lspci command

Tags: sd-card, dmesg, pci, lspci

Whenever I insert/remove SD card, my ubuntu doesn't recognize those behaviors automatically. I have to run `lspci` command to manually tell ubuntu about the hardware change.

I want to make my ubuntu automatically detect the SD card.
(auto-detecting the hardware change, not auto-mounting the file system)

Here is the detailed steps to use SD card on my ubuntu:

1. Insert SD card to the computer. No new messages on `dmesg`.
2. Run `lspci` command on terminal. Then the new messages appear on `dmesg`.
3. Mount the SD card and do something. When finished, unmount the SD card.
4. Remove SD card physically from the computer. `dmesg` says nothing about this detachment.
5. Run `lspci` command again. Then `dmesg` says `mmc0: card aaaa removed`.

Some additional information:

- I'm using ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with RTS5227 card reader.
- No problem with mount, read, write and unmount.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lengthy Q&A on Unix & Linux addresses this issue:

- [Udev triggers are not firing on insert of CF card into USB card reader (anymore)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38582/udev-triggers-are-not-firing-on-insert-of-cf-card-into-usb-card-reader-anymore)

After many pages of scrolling the solution is a new `udev` rule:

```
# enable in-kernel media-presence polling
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="block", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}=="0", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}="2000"
ACTION=="add", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1", ATTR{events_poll_msecs}="2000"
```

The Q&A is far too long to repost here, but please read the entire link to learn more.